# Claming of Estimote Proxitimity Beacon

Tags: android, beacon, estimote, google-beacon-platform

Our HR people bought the estimote Proximity Beacon kit through Amazon(india)
Link :https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01M7SREI7/?coliid=I14HT1PJZNTKQK&colid=WTRNR568YL5L&psc=0

i want to develop indoor tracking system using this kit, but when i am claiming the beacon estimote app says email sent to owners email id, and person who has bought these beacon through amazon is not receiving any claiming mails .He has registered on estimote cloud also.

I have read documentation of how to transfer beacon and all but owner is not receiving any mail what should I do?

Comment: Ensure that the email hasn't been placed in the spam email and you have the correct email address.  That said,  without any code references, your guess is as good as ours.  This question is more suitable for Estimote customer support rather than SO.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Estimote support.  If that does not solve your problem, initiate a return to Amazon and make a new purchase.

Comment: Its been  2 to 3 months since i got them, I do have mailed estimote support .Is there any other way to claim the beacons?

Comment: An alternative is to initiate a return to Amazon